Cannot change network interface card settings
I am trying to get my NIC to be set to 1000mbps which it is capable but it doesn't seem to work I tried using commands like:
 sudo ethtool -s enp2s0f1 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off

however it won't go through straight away it takes some time, and then my server is no longer visible in my network. I've also tried downloading the latest NIC Drivers and that hasn't seemed to fix it, and I don't know what else to try.

Use the ip command. sudo ip link set dev eth0 .... Read man ip ip-link.

@waltinator What ip link command changes physical link speed? I consider myself fairly familiar with the tool, but is unaware of any such option. Nor does the manpage mention it.

Why do you need to set the speed manually? Usually auto-negotiation will work fine, and if you don't do autonegotiation, you have to force both ends. In general, if 1GbE doesn't run at 1GbE, investigate cabling, don't try forcing.

@vidarlo  I have a cat5E cable that should be able to give out the 1GBPS, and the network transfer speeds seem to be set at and not go past 100mbps. Whereas I would like it to use as much of the data as it can. Every Network hardware I have supports 1GBPS its just my ubuntu server thats just not dishing out :(

Try a different cable. What NIC do you have? As I said - forcing is really only applicable if you can configure it at both ends.  Otherwise - as you have discovered - the result is lost connection

@vidarlo my NIC is the NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit and I have the latest drivers, I will try a different cable now

What you can do is to only announce 1GbE. That's still autonegotiation, but you claim to only support one speed. That only requires configuration on one end.

@vidarlo I managed to fix it thank you , I had actually noticed some cables were not cat5E. But even when I had changed them over still didn't until I made some of the right correction now it works. So thank you for bringing that to my attention, and I didn't need to use that command cause the auto negotiation is working :))))). You've lowkey made my day I don't think you know how much research I've done to try and fix this and nothing has previously helped

@Marley Consider accepting the answer I wrote as a summary :) As a sidenote: debugging such problems takes time. But you learn some patterns, and elimination is a good way to do things; change that damn cable and verify that it's not the issue.

In general, you should never force speed on one end only. As you've observed that will lead to a dropped connection.
If you need forcing, force at both ends. An alternative may be to only announce one speed, but still allow autonegotiation.
Furthermore, if GbE network cards does not autonegotiate to 1GbE, suspect cabling. Try a different cable to verify that the problem is configuration.
